# Typescript project setup (first time)

Tags: javascript, transpiler, visual-studio-code, typescript2.1

First off, I didn't see a clear answer after hours of googling, sorry if I overlooked something.

***Quick version***
With Typescript how can I move `node_modules` to `outDir` or am I going about things the wrong way?

***Long version***
I'm trying to get started with typescript and configuring the project seems to be the hardest part. My goal is to have my source code in `src/server` and my output to be in `bin/server`

Here is my tsconfig.json for reference:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "outDir": "../../bin",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "target": "ES2015",
        "typeRoots": [
        "../../node_modules/@types/"
        ]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "bin/*",
        "node_modules/*",
        "public/*",
        "**/*-aot.ts"
    ]
}
```

Here is the directory structure:

```
Project
+-/bin
|  +/server
|     +-server.js
+-/src
  +/server
    +-server.ts
    +-package.json
    +-/node_modules
       +-[...]
    +-/typings
       +-[...]
```

To compile from `~/Project` I use `tsc -p src/server`, boom we have `bin/server/server.js`.

To run I am using vs code, here is `launch.json`:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [{
        "outFiles": [ "${workspaceRoot}/bin/server/**/*.js" ],
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/server",
        "name": "Launch",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/server/server.ts",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "env": {
            "NODE_ENV": "development",
            "SERVER": "http://localhost:8080"
        }
    }]
}
```

The error I am getting is `Error: Cannot find module 'express'`, the module is installed in `src/server/node_modules/express` so I'm guessing I have to move `node_modules` to `bin/server` as well? That doesn't seem right.

Super new to typescript (started today) thanks for taking the time to read my long post.

PS: Assume everything is on version latest.

Answer (score 1):

Answer found!

I moved tsconfig.json to `src/server/` and ran `tsc -p src/server` from the project root.

Updated tsconfig.json for reference:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "outDir": "../../bin",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "target": "ES2015",
        "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types/"]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "bin/*",
        "node_modules/*",
        "public/*",
        "**/*-aot.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Turn into a solution to the problem by clicking the tick.